# Can I selectively ignore CSS warnings with PostCSS and Vite?

Tags: vite, postcss, sveltekit

While using Vite and PostCSS (via SvelteKit), I'm importing a stylesheet from a library which is using a deprecated selector, and I get a warning like so:

```
[vite:css] Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.
651|  @media print {
652|    /* Prevent printers from removing background-images of controls. */
653|    .leaflet-control {
   |       ^
654|            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
655|            color-adjust: exact;
```

I don't have control over this file so it would be nice to suppress warnings from just this library (and possibly all warnings from files imported from `node_modules`).

Can someone point me to where I might be able to do so in the Vite and/or PostCSS configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are a few options to resolve this:

- [Override the CSS for the particular property](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/8210#issuecomment-1144588041) in the application stylesheet.
- Fork and submit a PR to the library that has the deprecated property.
- [Use a plugin](https://github.com/dcalhoun/postcss-warn-cleaner). I didn't try this option as I decided I'd prefer to resolve the warning rather than ignore it.

Answer (score -1):

you can ignore CSS errors in your svelte config

```
// svelte.config.js

export default {
    ...
    onwarn: (warning, handler) => {
            const { code } = warning;
            if (code === 'css-unused-selector') {
                return;
            }

            handler(warning);
    },
    ...
};
```

EDIT: after [jrh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722758/jrh)'s comment on my answer, I remembered I also had some trouble ignoring warning while only following the doc at first, and it turns out I also added this to my .eslintrc.js :

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: ['svelte3'],
    overrides: [
        {
            files: ['*.svelte'],
            processor: 'svelte3/svelte3',
            settings: {
                'svelte3/ignore-styles': () => true,
                'svelte3/ignore-warnings': (warning) =>
                    warning.code.includes('selector')
                        || warning.code.includes('some-other-pattern')
            }
        }
    ],
    ...
};
```

my bad, when writing my answer I ran a search for 'unused-selector' and didn't catch that part of my code as it was 'selector' in that file.

Comment: Great idea. While this /should/ work according to [the SvelteKit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration), it doesn't seem to do anything in the current version of `@sveltejs/kit` (`1.0.0-next.348`). Or possibly the `[vite:css]` warning is coming from somewhere that Svelte's `onwarn` isn't catching it.